# Google Service Place picker setLatLngBounds() is not working(always shows current location by default)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using `PlacePicker` for selecting user's current location and to show its select location.Selecting Current location and getting its latitude and longitude is working fine but showing already selected location on map by passing latitude and longitude is not working its showing current location instead of select location.Here is my code, please help me to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.Thanks

```
private void openGoogleLocationScreen(String longitude,String latitude) {
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(longitude) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude)) {
    LatLng llg = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
    builder.setLatLngBounds(getLocationBounds(llg, 5500));
}
try {
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

`// To get LocationBounds of given Latitude and Longitude.`

```
private LatLngBounds getLocationBounds(LatLng location, int mDistanceInMeters) {
double latRadian = Math.toRadians(location.latitude);

double degLatKm = 110.574235;
double degLongKm = 110.572833 * Math.cos(latRadian);
double deltaLat = mDistanceInMeters / 1000.0 / degLatKm;
double deltaLong = mDistanceInMeters / 1000.0 / degLongKm;

double minLat = location.latitude - deltaLat;
double minLong = location.longitude - deltaLong;
double maxLat = location.latitude + deltaLat;
double maxLong = location.longitude + deltaLong;


return new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(minLat, minLong), new LatLng(maxLat, maxLong));
```

}